# ¿Como inicializar una variable constante?

Tags: java

Quiero inicializar una variable constante, la cual es ´final´, pero también quiero incluirla en el constructor de un clase pero no se si así esta bien:

```
public class Avion
{
    private final BigDecimal limiteAltura;
    public Avion(String limiteAltura)
    {
        this.limiteAltura = new BigDecimal(limiteAltura);
    }
}
```

Se supone que el constructor inicializa un campo con valores aptos. Se inicializa con un `String` que por defecto sera `null` pero me da la impresión que se puede hacer de otra manera. Una constante tiene que ser inicializada en el momento de su declaración o en el constructor. **Lo que quiero conseguir es ser explícito no obviar código.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private final BigDecimal limiteAltura;
```

No, aquí no la inicializas, aquí la declaras. Tiene el valor por defecto `null`, pero no la has inicializado.

Tu código es correcto; mientras sólo la inicialices una vez (al declararla o dentro de cada uno de los constructores) no hay problema.

Comment: El término `blank initialization`. ¿Que es?

Comment: Encontré el término en una referencia, pero no veo que se aplique de forma generalizada, así que mejor lo elimino.